# JAXB annotations not applied to referenced class in JBoss

Tags: xml, jboss, jaxb, annotations

I'm trying to marshall to XML a Class(A) that references another Class(B) that is not on the same project but on the classpath .  Somehow Jaxb is ignoring all annotations in B. Can this be made ? Or is there an alternative ?

Note: Running env : Jboss AS 7.1

Class A

```java
    package a.com;

    import b.com.b;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "enc")
    public class A
    {
        @XmlElement(name = "ref")
        public B reference;    
    }
```

Class B

```java
   package b.com;

   @XmlRootElement
   public class B
   {
       @XmlElement(name="class_id")
       public String id;
   }
```

POM of Project containing A :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>b</groupId>
        <artifactId>b-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The generated XML

```
 <enc>
    <ref>
        <id>XPTO</id>
    </ref>
 </enc>
```

Comment: Please post your code examples and a test case which fails.

Comment: The code has few syntax problems but looks OK for me. Check maybe if you have `@XmlAccessorType(PROPERTY)` on package `b`.

Comment: Have you tried running it outside your application server?

Comment: No , actually I didn't . I will give it a try .

Comment: Well , outside the application server it works just fine. All the annotations are respected. But when I run inside the application server, bang, B is marshalled as if no annotation has been written. Is it possible to substitute the annotation with a schema that would guide the marshalling process ?

Comment: This could be a JBoss bug, have you tried their support forums?  I have also updated your question title to indicate the problem is related to running in JBoss.

Comment: Check that you don't have a duplicate class `B` somewhere else.